# How do I install PHP and Apache on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

Just installed Ubuntu, for the first time. I can't find any beginner friendly on how to setup Apache and PHP (latest version together).

I am a Windows user, so I am used with a package named WampServer, any related tools on Ubuntu or  how would I set up a development environment with Apache, PHP 5.5 and MySQL on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Serverfault is for profesional adminstration problems, not for beginning question with a plenty of tutorials in the net.

Comment: Are you trying to use WAMPserver on Ubuntu? You'll need a LAMP stack, not a WAMP one.

Answer (score 1):

You could google the answer to this very easily.

## Installing using apt-get

You simply use the following command to install the applications...

`sudo apt-get install http php mysql-server`

## Setting up Apache

You would then place files in the `/var/www/public_html` folder (or similar). These files would show up when you browse to the public ipv4 address of the server on port 80.

If you wanted to set up multiple sites, identified by different public ipv4 addresses or hostnames, you would set up **VirtualHosts** inside your `httpd.conf` file, usually located at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd.conf`. There should be an example **VirtualHost** near the end of the config file (Press CTRL+G in Vi to go to the end of the file).

## Configuring PHP

To specify different options for PHP, you would simply edit the configuration file, usually located at `/etc/php.ini` or similar... I'm sure you can find it by typing the command: `sudo find / -name php*`

## Installing and configuring MySQL

Any way, the final step would be to set up mysql. You can do it manually, or you could just run the `/etc/mysql/mysql_secureinstallation` script (that may not be the exact location, again, you can use `sudo find / -name <search term>` to find the right file.)

and there you have it.

Easy as pie...

Next time use Google. Asking "stupid" questions is bound to get you the reputation of being an annoying person that doesn't do their research.

Peace

Comment: There's no such thing as a "stupid" question - just questions not 100% appropriate for this website. Just so you know.

Comment: I agree, that's why I put "stupid" in quotes. It's more of a matter of being responsible for how others perceive the question. Some people are not so understanding :)